# Updating RecyclerView Data when CheckBox is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I want to implement a `CheckBox` on a `RecyclerView.Adapter` But I don't know where to start right, I have previously read references from several articles related to the `CheckBox` on the `RecyclerView` but there are no articles that match my problem.

I have a response from an API like this :

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "isNameChecked": false,
            "name": "Data A",
            "data": [
                {
                    "isChecked": false,
                    "id": "A1",
                    "name": "Data 1"
                },
                {
                    "isChecked": true,
                    "id": "A2",
                    "name": "Data 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "isNameChecked": true,
            "name": "Data B",
            "data": [
                {
                    "isChecked": true,
                    "id": "B1",
                    "name": "Data 1"
                },
                {
                    "isChecked": true,
                    "id": "B2",
                    "name": "Data 2"
                },
                {
                    "isChecked": true,
                    "id": "B3",
                    "name": "Data 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If the `CheckBox` **All** is `true`, all the existing `CheckBox` will be set `true` (`isNameChecked` and `isChecked`) automatically and save the `id` (`A1`, `A2`, `B2`, etc.) if the `id` is **true** from `data` into a Variable

[image: When CheckBox All is true]

Otherwise, if the `All` box is **false**, but `isNameChecked` set **true**, the `data` in the result will update `isChecked` as **true**

[image: When CheckBox All is false]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you're displaying your checkboxes, but your adapter should have the data for all the items stored in it, and part of that data is whether the item is checked or not. I think you have two approaches:

- Make the `All` checkbox set/unset the checked status of all its child items (i.e. iterate through your list, map or whatever and change all the values) and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (or another `notify` method) so the display updates
- Don't change the children's checked states (so if you uncheck `All`, the others "remember" if they were checked or not) and just decide whether they should *display* as checked based on the top-level boxes

In your adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method (where it sets up the display for an item, including whether it shows as checked or not) you can find the parent checkbox, and if it's checked you can display the child as checked too. Otherwise show its actual state (the real value set in the data).

That's just the basic idea, you'll have to work out how to fit it in with what you're actually doing and how you're representing that hierarchy in your data, but it's one way you can approach it!